# QNetworkRequest to download an image?

Tags: qt

I have used `QNetworkRequest` to retrieve xml off the web without problems:

```
request.setUrl(QUrl("http://api.somesite.com/api/4we35r/somefile.xml"));

myNetworkAccessManager->get(request);
```

How would I go about downloading an image? Ex:

```
http://www.mysite.com/27eye28/images/myimage.png
```

Do I just replace the xml url above with the png url? Do I have to do anything special?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, replacing the URL is all that you have to do.

Here's a working example,

```
void MainWindow::GetImage(QString url)
{
    QNetworkAccessManager* manager = new QNetworkAccessManager(this);
    connect(manager, SIGNAL(finished(QNetworkReply *)), this, SLOT(replyFinished(QNetworkReply *)));

    QUrl url = QUrl(url);

    QNetworkRequest request(url);

    manager->get(request);
}

void MainWindow::replyFinished(QNetworkReply *reply)
{
    if(reply->error() != QNetworkReply::NoError)
    {
        ui->textBrowser->setText("Error: " +  reply->errorString());
    }
    else
    {
        QByteArray responseData = reply->readAll();
        QFile file("d:\\myImage.png");
        file.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly);
        file.write((responseData));
        file.close();
    }
}
```